# PS - Parameter's default value in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: string, visual-studio, powershell, parameters

I'm making a PowerShell script, and I've found something strange happening with my Visual Studio 2015. When I'm trying to assign value to sciript's parameter, it becomes blank. However in clean powershell console, everything is ok. Here is my code, and results for VS and clean PS:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
     [String]$parameter = $PSScriptRoot
)

$var = "\file.txt"
echo "PSScriptRoot: $PSScriptRoot"
echo "Parameter: $parameter"

$var1 = $PSScriptRoot + $var
$var2 = $parameter + "\file.txt"
$var3 = $parameter + $var
-Join ($parameter, $var)

echo "var1: $var1"
echo $var1.GetType()
echo "var2: $var2"
echo $var2.GetType()
echo "var3: $var3"
echo $var3.GetType()
echo "var: $var"
echo $var.GetType()
echo "parameter: $parameter"
```

Results VS2015:

```
PSScriptRoot: C:\Users\Ja\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp
Parameter: 
\file.txt
var1: C:\Users\Ja\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp\file.txt

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------            
True     True     String                                   System.Object       
var2: \file.txt
True     True     String                                   System.Object       
var3: \file.txt
True     True     String                                   System.Object       
var: \file.txt
True     True     String                                   System.Object       
parameter:
```

Results clean PowerShell:

```
PSScriptRoot: C:\users\ja\documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp
Parameter: C:\users\ja\documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp
C:\users\ja\documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp\file.txt
var1: C:\users\ja\documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp\file.txt
System.String
var2: C:\users\ja\documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp\file.txt
System.String
var3: C:\users\ja\documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp\file.txt
System.String
var: \file.txt
System.String
parameter: C:\users\ja\documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\teststemp\teststemp
```

Does anyone knows, why it's happening? Switching to Release mode didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer by myself.

The main problem is, that any IDE runs code with some kind of "virtual container", made specially for it, and because of that, some built-in parameters cannot be initialised with correct values, because those values doesn't exist.

In this case, when I try to get $PSScriptRoot variable value, it returns nothing, because the script is running from non-existing directory. And in clean PowerShell console, execution looks like:

```
& ("C:\Scripts\script.ps1")
```

So the script is not running from this "virtual container", but from specified directory, and $PSScriptRoot now have value.

Because of this, there is problem with debugging scripts like this one. As far as I know, you cannot add block of if statement before parameters block, to check, if $PSScriptRoot has value, like that:

```
if ($PSScriptRoot -eq $null) {
    $PSScriptRoot = "C:\something"
}

[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
     [String]$cfgFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\cfg.txt"
)
```

This will return a lot of exceptions and errors.

I've found solution for this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
         [String]$PSScriptRoot,
         [String]$cfgFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\cfg.txt"
    )
```

So we can just give value in parameters, and in release version delete additional unneeded parameter.